# Regex for group of any character ranging from minimum to maximum

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to make a character class of all alphabets,numbers and punctuations then  specifying it's range but it is not working. [A-Za-z0-9_.-\,]{,5}

I'm trying to get a match for  groups of 'any character' ranging from one limit to the other like for the match of similar kind with Alphabets you would use "[A-Za-z]{,5}" but the problem is this only works for alphabets or numbers but I want my expression to match any character (puntuations,alphabets,numbers).

I tried things like ".{,5}" and "(.*?)" and  but it is not ranged it would match everything in  between.

```
string pattern = @"[A-Za-z0-9]{,10}";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text,pattern);
foreach(var match in matches)
{
     MessageBox.Show(match.Value.ToString());
}
```

for example I want to match everything ranging from {,10} after "NN" from this string "Estragon_NN,_,sitting_VBG [PRESP]" but I am only getting "NN" back as the result

Comment: `NN([A-Za-z0-9,_]{,10})` will this help? I speculate `.` matches any character and everything is a match

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "ranged". Can you show some example strings and example matches? Also, why doesn't `.{,5}` work?

Comment: there's no such thing as `{,10}` only `{10,x}` exits (or `{10,}` ) . You could write  `[A-Za-z0-9]`{0,10} which will give any sentence(in English) or number that their length is between 0 and 10 characters. Edit also `match` has no `Value` property

Comment: `{,10}` should be written as `{0,10}`. What do you want to achieve? You have `Estragon_NN,_,sitting_VBG [PRESP]`, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
string pattern = @"([^_]+)_NN(?<capturedGroup>[a-zA-Z0-9_\[\],\s]{0,10})";
var matches = Regex.Match("Estragon_NN,_,sitting_VBG [PRESP]",pattern);
var result = matches.Groups["capturedGroup"].Value;
```

Can verify it here
https://regex101.com/r/OVyZ3b/1